# Dealing with one scripted pipeline parameters overwriting another

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a setup with 2 scripted pipelines (both In shared library)

Pipeline A :

caller.groovy

Pipeline B :
consumeMe.groovy

they both have parameters of their own (properties.parameters)
each one of them is a shared library of its own, standalone they work great no issues.
The thing is I have a scenario where I go to Jenkins UI, I set the parameters I want for caller, some of these parameters are used later on to feed "consumeMe"

The thing is, Once caller executes consumeMe , consumeMe populate the initial (caller) parameters in UI with consumeMe parameters, how can I overcome this issue? it requires me to run caller once again (which will fail because there's a mismatch in parameters) and only than it will register the default values of caller.

Is there a way right after the execution of consumeMe finishes to reapply the caller parameters so the next time I click build with parameters it will show me the actual caller parameters and not "Dummy" parameters of consumeMe?

I was looking into :
currentBuild.replaceAction(currentBuild.getAction(hudson.model.ParametersAction.class))

no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

It *probably* might work if you define a method with that `properties([parameters([ ... ])])` block and call it twice (before and after the call of `consumeMe`).

But it really seems that it's better to redesign your pipelines because even if you deal with the pipeline parameters dynamically in this case, you might end up facing exactly the same issues a bit later - because Jenkins can update the job parameter only after the build is triggered.

Imagine you have two pipelines (upstream and downstream) that should use the same set of options for a `choice` parameter, and the first one triggers the second one using `build` step. If you run the first pipeline with a new value, the second one will not start because Jenkins validates the `choice` options before the pipeline start - thus using the old set of choices. If I recall correctly, Jenkins will not even mark the first job as failed, so you'll have to figure it out by yourself.

The only way to resolve that lock will be to run the second pipeline manually, stop it after it reads the new Jenkinsfile but right before it takes any further action, check if the new set of parameters was applied, and re-run the first pipeline. You can try to add to the second pipeline a stage that stops the execution automatically if the new set of parameter values does not correspond to the old one, but now the first one will fail.

So I'd simply recommend to refrain from trying and invest that time in simplification of the pipelines.